# Including library header file

Tags: c, gcc, ffmpeg, openssl

I've installed **`OpenSSL`**, and put the header files in **`/usr/include`**.

So when I compile this very simple program, it works just fine with `gcc` and `clang`:

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
void main() {}
```

Now I'm trying to compile `FFmpeg` with `OpenSSL`. I've include the appropriate flags, but **`./configure`** gets hung up here:

```
/Users/..../ffmpeg-2.2.1/libavformat/network.c:40:10: fatal error: 'openssl/ssl.h' file not found
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [libavformat/network.o] Error 1
```

Any idea why it wouldn't recognize the location of openssl? I'm stumped.

Comment: Odd as it seems, the only logical conclusion is that ./configure does not establish a INCLUDE path that includes /usr/include. Send this through the preprocessor with verbose output if needed to establish where it is looking, and thus why it is failing.

Comment: Thanks man, you were right. The configure file was changing the include flag.

Comment: I somewhat suspected as-such.